# Is IPAD-X/Y and PAD-X/Y different in tkinter (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Tell me the difference between **pad-x/y** and **ipad-x/y**.
Are both same OR not

Comment: **ipadx, ipady** − How many pixels to pad widget, horizontally and vertically, *inside* widget's borders.


**padx, pady** − How many pixels to pad widget, horizontally and vertically, *outside* v's borders.

Comment: Or as I would like to remember, `ipadx` to be short for inner-padx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ipadx, ipady** − How many pixels to pad widget, horizontally and vertically, inside widget's borders.
**padx, pady** − How many pixels to pad widget, horizontally and vertically, outside v's borders

Example:
Here is `ipadx`. You can see the that the width has increased. It means that 20 pixels are there to the right and left of the Label. 20 pixels are padded horizontally. Similarly it  is for `ipady` except it is vertical.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
Label(root,bg='light grey',text="Hello").grid(row=0,column=0,ipadx=20)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

And here it is in case of `padx`. The widget is placed 20 pixels to the side, horizontally. Same is the case for `pady` except it is vertical.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
Label(root,bg='light grey',text="Hello").grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]